# Storing tsv data in a list and looping through it

Tags: c#, linq, visual-studio-2008, csv

I want to store some data from a tsv to a list. Store some other data from another tsv to another list. Loop through the first list and keep only the rows that contain the data from the second list. I don't know how to store data in a list, have used var and array for now. here is the code.

**file 1 sample:**

heading heading heading heading \n

data       data     abc     data

data      data      bbc     data

**file 2**

abc
bbc
cbc

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] appcode = File.ReadAllLines(@"d:\data\542112107\Desktop\project 1\Project1\Project1\bin\Debug\app_test.txt");

            List<string> appcodeList = new List<string>();
            appcodeList = appcode.ToList();
            var records = (from l in File.ReadAllLines(@"d:\data\542112107\Desktop\project 1\Project1\Project1\bin\Debug\instance_test.txt")
                           let pieces = l.Split('\t')
                           select new { Col1 = pieces[0], Col2 = pieces[1], Col3 = pieces[2], Col4 = pieces[3] }
                           )
                .Skip(1)
                .Distinct()
                .OrderBy(c => c.Col3).ToList();
            List<string> AllDataList = new List<string>();
            AllDataList = records.ToList();
           foreach (var r in records)
            { Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}, {2},{3}", r.Col1, r.Col2, r.Col3, r.Col4); }

            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Press return key to exit!");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Okay Brother, will keep that in mind.

Comment: do help me if you can. ;)

Comment: So assuming you read tsv1 into list1, and tsv2 into list2 - do you want all lines that are present in both list1 and list2? Essentially a list intersection?

Comment: Actually, I would like to do a filter in the first with the second. A loop which will find if the data that is present in the second list is also in the first one. If yes then display, if no then wont be displayed, kind of a union rather than an intersection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var list1 = File.ReadAllLines("file1.tsv"); 
var list2 = File.ReadAllLines("file2.tsv").Select(x=>x.Trim()); 

//select col3 from list1
foreach (var x in list1.Select(y=>y.Split("\t")[2]) { 
   if (list2.Contains(x.Trim())) { 
      Console.WriteLine(x); 
   } 
}
```

Once you get that working, you can convert list2 (or list1 whichever is smaller) into a lookup ... (`.ToLookup()`) which will dramatically speed up the `.Contains()` operation. The current algo is O(N x M) which you can reduce to O(N Log M).

Comment: 1) You should probably use a `HashSet`, rather than either a `List` or `Lookup`. 2) `Lookup` has O(1) search speed, not O(Log(n)) search speed.

Comment: hey, tried your method, it wont diplay anything. No errors but nothing to display.

Comment: tried this for hashset, no luck
 HashSet<string> hashset = (HashSet<string>);
            hashset = File.ReadAllLines(@"d:\data\542112107\Desktop\project 1\Project1\Project1\bin\Debug\app_test.txt");

Comment: hey, I updated the question so that you can look at the sample file